Floating UI setFloating with custom component that accepts RefObject
I'm attempting to use Floating UI with various custom react components.
The custom components internally create element references (to do focus, measurements, etc.) but they each can also accept and use a RefObject in the event a consumer needs to get a hold of the underlying root html element for reasons.
Floating-UI's useFloating hook returns an object with a setFloating function that is to be passed to the relevant component ref, allowing floating ui to position the component. However, because setFloating is not an actual RefObject, this breaks the custom component behavior. (see example) Ideally, here, I'd have an actual RefObject from useFloating I could pass along.
Floating UI does include a mergeRef function that seems applicable, but it does not return a RefObject either (so I can't create a normal ref and merge it with setFloating and pass that along).
Alternatively, I could wrap the custom component in a div and pass Floating UI's setFloating to that, and this may be what I do, but it really feels like I should be able to go from useFloating to some Component without extra cruft so long as the component  exposes its root node.
Is it possible to use floating ui's react hook with some arbitrary custom react component that exposes its underlying node, without modifying the custom component?
Example:
const App = ()=>{
    const { refs, ... } = useFloating<HTMLDivElement>({ ... })
    return <div>        
        {...}
        <Custom ref={refs.setFloating} ... /> 
    </div>
}

const Custom = React.ForwardRef((
    props:{...},
    forwardedRef:React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
)=>{
    const internalRef = useRef();
    const selectRef = forwardedRef ?? internalRef
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        // ...
        selectRef.current... // This breaks when using custom component with floating UI because useFloating's refs.setFloating is not an actual RefObject with a current property.  
    })
    return <div ref={selectRef}>Hi</div>    
})


Could you clarify what you mean by "This pattern doesn't work"? Do you mean that when you tried using ref forwarding with a custom component, it didn't function as expected? or you have problem with the code inside useEffect or internalRef in the Custom component?

Apologies, I've attempted to clarify the central question.

you are passing the refs.setFloating as a function reference to the ref of the component, to be called and connect the element node to the usefloating API, so if you need the actual ref of the element you should use the refs.reference
const App = ()=>{
const { refs, ... } = useFloating<HTMLDivElement>({ ... })

return (
    <div>        
       {...}
       <Custom setRef={refs.setFloating} actualElementRef={refs.reference} ... /> 
    </div>
)}

 function Custom (props) {
   const internalRef = useRef();
   const selectRef = props.actualElementRef ?? internalRef;

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("selectRef", selectRef.current);
   });

   return <div ref={props.setRef}>Hi</div>;
 };

You can also use the forward ref instead of actualElementRef in my above example, but I just want to make it more explicit with the naming
it would be like this
const App = ()=>{
const { refs, ... } = useFloating<HTMLDivElement>({ ... })

return (
    <div>        
       {...}
       <Custom setRef={refs.setFloating} ref={refs.reference} ... /> 
    </div>
)}

const Custom = forwardRef(function Custom(props, ref) {
  const internalRef = useRef();
  const selectRef = ref ?? internalRef;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectRef", selectRef.current);
  });

  return <div ref={props.setRef}>Hi</div>;
});


Apologies, changing the behavior of the Custom components is out of bounds.
